# Python: How to decipher a Caesar Cipher by multipling each item in a list by all the items in another list?

Tags: python, list, output, multiplication, encryption

I need to know how to multiply two lists together so that each item in one list is multiplied by all the items in another list and the output has to be in a list. Its for decipher a Caesar ciper by retrieving the value for the shift which would be k. The value in the new list which is the highest used the value of k that I want as an output. The question asks that the maximum value for the summation of `tfreq[i]*counts[i+k]` where `i=range(26)` and `tfreq` is the typical frequency of letters occurring and `counts` is the frequency that letters occur in the text.Here's what I have so far

```
def bestShift(file):
     """Enter file name in quotations. Used to find the shift 'k' for a Caeser cipher"""
     infile = open(file)
     text = infile.read()
     text = text.lower()
     text = ''.join(char for char in text if char.isalpha())
     text_length = len(text)
     counts = [0]*26
     stats = open('stats.txt')#the typical frequencies put into a txt file
     tfreq = stats.read()
     tfreq = tfreq.split()
     tfreq = [float(item) for item in tfreq]#converts strings in list to float

    for i in range(26):
        for k in range(26):
        char=lowercase[i]
        counts[i] = 100*text.count(char)/text_length
        t = [q*r for q,r in zip(tfreq[i],counts[i+k])]
```

Please note that both the lists counts and tfreq contain only floats.
If you don't know what a caeser cipher is it takes an input of text and changes all the letters according to the shift given. So the letters slide along so many places
Example

```
import string
def encrypt(text,shift):
    """Enter the text in quotations. Encrypts entire paragraphs"""
    table = dict(zip(string.ascii_lowercase, string.ascii_lowercase[shift:] +       string.ascii_lowercase[:shift]))
    table.update(zip(string.ascii_uppercase, string.ascii_uppercase[shift:] + string.ascii_uppercase[:shift]))
    return ''.join(table.get(ch, ch) for ch in text)
```

Output

```
>>> encrypt('example',2)
'gzcorng'
```

Comment: Fix the indentation, please.

Comment: and give sample input and output for those unfamiliar with a caesar cipher

Comment: How to brute force caesar's cypher has been answered on SO like 5 billion times and google yields another zillion results.

Comment: See the article of Peter Norvig (http://norvig.com/ngrams/), which gives the answer in Python (228ff.).